# Pre-populated link URLs with search results

Tags: feature-request

One really cool feature of Google Docs is that when you highlight a word and click on "add link" button, it pre-populate the URL fields with some suggestions from search results of the highlighted text.

[image]

I know Google Search does not have an API so StackOverflow can't use Google APIs to achieve this, but Bing and DockDockGo have their APIs and their results are good enough for most cases. Of course there is costs involved with this which I have no idea how much it's going to be and if StackOverflow want to pay that premium. But it would be really nice to see this in StackExchange websites.

#### Use Case

When I'm answering question in Stack Overflow, sometimes I write something like this:

```
You need to use jQueryUI for this problem.
```

Now, I want to link word "jQueryUI" to it's website. If it was Google Docs, I would just highlight it and click anchor icon. Google would give me a link to jQueryUI in their pre-populated URL box. I would just click on that. Now in Stack Overflow, I have to open a new tab, search for jQueryUI and then copy link to their website, bring it back to Stack Overflow and paste it.

Comment: Isn't this more of a feature request for Google? What would we change? It might help if you included a link or two.

Comment: No, it's a feature request for SE. I'm hoping SE match this feature of Google Docs when editing question/answers. To try this feature in Google, just open a Google Doc and highlight text then click the anchor button.

Comment: Ah. I get it now. (I was confused because I always enter links with the keyboard and not the mouse.) Could you describe the use case you have in mind?

Comment: @JonEricson updated my question

Comment: What I often do is highlight the term, right click and select "Search Google for 'term'". It's not as easy as what you're suggesting but still easier than manually opening a new tab and then searching.